# IXmlSerializable Validate Against Schema

Tags: c#, xml, serialization, xsd, schema

I'm implementing `IXmlSerializable` for custom (de)serialization logic of my class but want the reading and writing of XML to be checked against an XSD schema. I have added the `XmlSchemaProviderAttribute`:

```
[XmlSchemaProvider("ConfigSchema")]
[XmlRoot("Config")]
public class Config
{
    // properties, fields and methods incl. interface methods

    public static XmlQualifiedName ConfigSchema(XmlSchemaSet xs)
    {
        const string xsdPath = "./Config.xsd";

        var serializer = new XmlSerializer(typeof(XmlSchema));
        var schema = (XmlSchema)serializer.Deserialize(new XmlTextReader(xsdPath), null);

        xs.XmlResolver = new XmlUrlResolver();
        xs.Add(schema);

        return new XmlQualifiedName("Config", "namespace");
    }
}
```

The schema loads fine and (de)serialization works as expected but there is no validation.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<xs:schema id="ConfigSchema" 
    targetNamespace="namespace"
    elementFormDefault="qualified"
    xmlns="namespace"
    xmlns:xs="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema">
    <xs:complexType name="Config">
        <xs:all>
            <xs:element name="Config">
                <xs:complexType>
                    <xs:all>
                        <xs:element name="name" type="xs:string" />
                        <xs:element name="timeout" type="xs:time" />
                        <xs:element name="points" minOccurs="1">
                            <xs:complexType>
                                <xs:sequence>
                                    <xs:element name="point" minOccurs="1" maxOccurs="unbounded">
                                        <xs:complexType>
                                            <xs:all>
                                                <xs:element name="a" type="xs:int" />
                                                <xs:element name="b" type="xs:int" />
                                                <xs:element name="c" type="xs:int" />
                                            </xs:all>
                                        </xs:complexType>
                                    </xs:element>
                                </xs:sequence>
                            </xs:complexType>
                        </xs:element>
                    </xs:all>
                </xs:complexType>
            </xs:element>
        </xs:all>
    </xs:complexType>
</xs:schema>
```

If I deserialize the following against the above schema no exception is thrown (`<timeout>` is missing but specified under `<xs:all>` in the schema):

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8" ?>
    <Config
        xmlns:xsi="http://w3.org/2001/XMLScehma-instance"
        xsi:schemaLocation="namespace Config.xsd">
        <name>some name</name>
        ...
```

**Edit:** Here's how I run it

```
string path = "./serviceconfig.xml";
var serializer = new XmlSerializer(typeof(Config));
var cfg = (Config)serializer.Deserialize(new XmlTextReader(path), null);
```

What is the 'correct'/'best' way to validate the incomming/outgoing XML against the schema?

**Edit #2:** More info

Here's the complete XML

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8" ?>
    <Config
        xmlns:xsi="http://w3.org/2001/XMLScehma-instance"
        xsi:schemaLocation="namespace Config.xsd">
        <name>some name</name>
        <timeout>10</timeout>
        <points>
            <point>
                <a>5</a>
                <b>7</b>
                <c>11</c>
            </point>
            <point>
                <a>8</a>
                <b>7</b>
                <c>3</c>
            </point>
        </points>
    </Config>
```

I've tried looking into XmlReaderSettings in `ReadXml(XmlReader reader)` with the following which has not helped

```
var settings = new XmlReaderSettings
{
    ValidationType = ValidationType.Schema,
    Schemas = _schemaSet
};

settings.ValidationEventHandler += (sender, args) => Console.WriteLine(args.Message);
reader = XmlReader.Create(reader, settings);
```

`_schema` is set from the static `ConfigSchema()` above.

Comment: Please post your full schema. Also, what is the problem exactly? You say you can deserialise fine, however you think this is incorrect?

Comment: I don't know how to validate the XML that is to (de)serialized against the schema.

Comment: I have edited your title. Please see, "[Should questions include “tags” in their titles?](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/19190/)", where the consensus is "no, they should not".

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After much digging and with help form Hugh's answer I was able to crack this nut.

1. I added the namespace to my XML and C# class:

   ```
   <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8" ?>
   <Config xlmns="namespace" ...
   ```

   and

   ```
   [XmlSchemaProvider("ConfigSchema")]
   [XmlRoot(Namespace="namespace", ElementName="Config")]
   public class Config : IXmlSerializable
   {
      private static XmlSchemaSet _schema;

      public static XmlQualifiedName ConfigSchema(XmlSchemaSet xs)
      {
         _schema = xs;
         // rest of method as OP
      }

      public void ReadXml(XmlReader reader)
      {
         var settings = new XmlReaderSettings
         {
            ValidationType = ValidationType.Schema,
            Schemas = _schemas;
         }

         settings.ValidationEventHandler += ValidationCallBack;
         reader = XmlReader.Create(reader, settings);
         reader.Read(); // your own read logic
      }

      // rest of class
   }
   ```
2. My XSD was all wrong. I had confused type definition with element structure definition.

   ```
   <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
   <xs:schema id="ServiceConfigSchema" 
     targetNamespace="namespace"
     elementFormDefault="qualified"
     xmlns="namespace"
     xmlns:xs="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema">  

     <xs:complexType name="point">
       <xs:all>
         <xs:element name="a" type="xs:int" />
         <xs:element name="b" type="xs:int" />
         <xs:element name="c" type="xs:int" />
       </xs:all>
     </xs:complexType>

     <xs:complexType name="points">
       <xs:sequence>
         <xs:element name="point" type="point" minOccurs="1" maxOccurs="unbounded" />
       </xs:sequence>
     </xs:complexType>

     <xs:complexType name="Config">
       <xs:all>
         <xs:element name="name" type="xs:string" />
         <xs:element name="timeout" type="xs:time" />
         <xs:element name="points" type="points" />
       </xs:all>
     </xs:complexType>

     <xs:element name="Config" type="Config" />
   </xs:schema>
   ```

Comment: I must say, I find it somewhat irregular that you have essentially collated my answer into your own answer and then awarded it to yourself. The schema above is semantically identical to the one I posted, ditto the XML. Granted you needed to make your serialization code work but that particular solution could have been expressed as an amendment to your original post, or a comment on mine. Not quite sure what else to say.

Comment: Your response was very helpful but it didnt solve the issue as it was purely looking at the XML (and I mentioned your positive contribution at the very start). A complete answer needed more to it wrt to the C# as my question was not how to write a valid schema for my XML, but how to validate it through C#. Anyway, not interested in awaring anything to myself so feel free to unmark it or have it unmarked if that makes you feel better. This answer is the 'complete solution' to my question (as far as my understanding goes anyway) as it covered XML, XSD and C#.

Answer (score 4):

The XML is not validating because your schema specifies a `targetNamespace = "namespace"` but your XML instance does not reference this namespace using a xmlns.

So the validator doesn't know how to validate your XML because it doesn't realise that your XML uses types defined in your schema.

If you post your full schema and xml instance I will be able to make a working sample.

**UPDATE**

Thanks for posting your schema. Where did you get it? The reason I ask is that it doesn't define any root node, just a type called Config.

If you remove the outer Complex Type element:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<xs:schema id="ConfigSchema"
    targetNamespace="namespace"
    elementFormDefault="qualified"
    xmlns="namespace"
    xmlns:xs="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema">
  <xs:element name="Config">
    <xs:complexType>
      <xs:all>
        <xs:element name="name" type="xs:string" />
        <xs:element name="timeout" type="xs:time" />
        <xs:element name="points" minOccurs="1">
          <xs:complexType>
            <xs:sequence>
              <xs:element name="point" minOccurs="1" maxOccurs="unbounded">
                <xs:complexType>
                  <xs:all>
                    <xs:element name="a" type="xs:int" />
                    <xs:element name="b" type="xs:int" />
                    <xs:element name="c" type="xs:int" />
                  </xs:all>
                </xs:complexType>
              </xs:element>
            </xs:sequence>
          </xs:complexType>
        </xs:element>
      </xs:all>
    </xs:complexType>
  </xs:element>
</xs:schema>
```

I was able to validate the following instance:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8" ?>
<Config xmlns="namespace">
  <name>some name</name>
  <timeout>13:20:00.000-05:00</timeout>
  <points>
    <point>
      <a>5</a>
      <b>7</b>
      <c>11</c>
    </point>
    <point>
      <a>8</a>
      <b>7</b>
      <c>3</c>
    </point>
  </points>
</Config>
```

Note that "10" is NOT a valid value for the timeout column according to the schema. When I tried I got this error:

> The 'namespace:timeout' element is invalid - The value '10' is invalid
>   according to its datatype 'http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema:time' -
>   The string '10' is not a valid XsdDateTime value.

Comment: I added `<Config xmlns="namespace" ...` but this threw an exception on deserialization: "<Config xmlns='namespace'> was not expected."

Comment: Thanks. I made it myself. Originally I did not havce the wrapping `<xs:complexType>` however my XmlSerializer was complainging about an unknown type 'Config' for the namespace...adding the complexType tag solved this. Could you share your C# code and how you valided/deserialized the XML for a complete picture, thanks.

Comment: I didn't write any code - just used a free tool http://www.utilities-online.info/xsdvalidation.